# Multiple recyclerview issue

Tags: android

I am trying to create an XML layout for football teams statistics and add who scored the goal for each team on the side of the vertical red view

After some work i created this layout:

[image]

This is my layout xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_team1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/placemahdi"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_team2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/placemahdi"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/versus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_stadium"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text=":"
        android:textSize="25sp" />



    <com.github.pavlospt.CircleView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/point1"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:cv_titleText="2"
        app:cv_titleSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/versus"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/versus"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:cv_titleColor="@color/white"
        app:cv_subtitleText=""
        app:cv_strokeColorValue="@color/colorGreen"
        app:cv_backgroundColorValue="@color/yellow"
        app:cv_fillColor="@color/yellow"
        app:cv_fillRadius="0.9"
        app:cv_strokeWidthSize="3"/>

    <com.github.pavlospt.CircleView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/point2"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:cv_titleText="2"
        app:cv_titleSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/versus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/versus"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:cv_titleColor="@color/white"
        app:cv_subtitleText=""
        app:cv_strokeColorValue="@color/colorGreen"
        app:cv_backgroundColorValue="@color/yellow"
        app:cv_fillColor="@color/yellow"
        app:cv_fillRadius="0.9"
        app:cv_strokeWidthSize="3"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="ahed2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/point2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/point2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="ahed2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/point1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/point1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/point1" />

</RelativeLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:background="#a40404" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textSize="20sp"
         />


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my layout inflater where i added a recyclerview:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_post"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </ScrollView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is an image i am following :

[image]

I just want to add the player who scored the goal with the football icon foreach side of the vertical red line.

Should i create two recyclerview?

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Go with single RecycleView ,and customise you recycleview's item like Left TextView(for Team1 player), circular view for time  and behind circular view draw view for red line and  Right TextView(for Team2 player),and while binding data to view in adapter ,hide one of the textview and assign time to circular view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using LinearLayout with weight property you can reslove this issue..

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="49"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

try this..

Comment: Thanks for your reply should i remove the vertical red line from the layout xml and add this one u added to my layout inflater ?

Comment: answer updated with a View in center .. if it seems to be useful ..please accept this answer .. happy coding.. :)

Comment: Ok thanks one more thing..In my code should i do this :

        recycler_one.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

or both like :

        recycler_one.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recycler_two.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

Comment: both are two different recycler views ..  so you should add properties separately  for each one...  like : recycler_one.setLayoutManager(layoutManager); recycler_two.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);